# Visual Studio Shortcut for Github Extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-extensions

If you have the Github Extension installed in Visual Studio, is it possible to configure a shortcut to navigate to the Github Window/Tab? Something similar to ctrl-alt-L which navigates to Solution Explorer.

Comment: I checked whether you could open it with [mnemonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonics_(keyboard)) by opening View / Other / GitHub, but the GitHub item doesn't have one defined.

Comment: I checked that initially. There are may native items in that menu which don't have assigned commands. So, I'm wondering if VS can support assigning commands to extension items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the command and set the shortcut to Ctrl+G, Ctrl+H.

[image: Visual Studio Keyboard Preferences]

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you wanted but, take a look at [this list](http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2017/) of shortcuts for Visual studio.

Comment: Thanks Matt :) I think that list is for VS native functionality, so I don't think it would include shortcuts for extensions.